# Using Passive RFID tags and UHF Readers for stock take

Tags: rfid

Stock take definition: Counting on-hand inventory in a premises in regular intervals to ensure it matches with the inventory count in your inventory mgt software.

Is it viable to mount fixed UHF readers on the ceiling of a huge premises (e.g. warehouse) that holds a lot of inventory instead of having to scan the rfid tags on every product one by one with a handheld reader? We use a fixed UHF reader to do this.

Comment: It can and is done, but there are a lot of issues that can come up in the process. It's best to get a professional to set this up for you.

Comment: Looks like that will be the best thing to do. Not many people work with RFID technology here in Kenya. I'll see if I can hire someone from abroad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The read range of passive UHF systems may be as long as 12 m, so you must take this into consideration.

However, UHF RFID is also the most sensitive to interference, when compared to LF and HF RFID's. Interferences most commonly experienced with RFID systems result from environmental factors in the deployment.

Older tags mounted on metal or on containers of liquids both provide significant interference.

> Recent developments in tag and antenna design and tuning have allowed
>   these problems to be overcome provided they are considered at the
>   planning stage. Also interference can be caused in UHF systems by
>   reflection or re-radiation of power signals.

With proper expertise in this field such a system may be set up  according to your needs. This very much depends on your warehouse environment and how far away the readers and tags are from each other.

You may either get a professional to implement this system or else start off with a simple test: Try scanning products from a distance that is similar in your warehouse. If this works as expected, then you may proceed.

Comment: +1 It also depends on the size of the product. Stock of 2ft cube cartons is way different from bins of matchbox sized metal parts.

Comment: Thank you Cyber for that insight. I'll set up a small demo to test it out first and then deploy.